# First item in Map returning null when getting key value while iterating through List

Tags: apex, map, csv, custom-metadata

I'm building a `List<String>` with the column header row from a CSV file to iterate through and get the API value from a `Map<String,String>` that is built from custom metadata.

The issue I'm having is the first column from the CSV is always returning `null` when retrieving the value from the map.

I know it is not an issue with the strings not matching because if I duplicate the column with the same header name the second column returns the correct API value from the map. The correct map value is returned if I hard code the key in my `map.get('key');` call.

Here is my debug log:

[image: debug log]

[106] is the List from the CSV column header;
[111] is the column header string; 
[112] is the value from the map

Code for making map from custom metadata:

```
Map<String, String> fieldMapping = new Map<String, String>();

for (Custom_Metadata__mdt str : [SELECT Id, Column_Header__c, Object_Field_API_Name__c FROM Custom_Metadata__mdt]){
    fieldMapping.put(str.Column_Header__c, str.Object_Field_API_Name__c);
}
```

Code to make list from CSV column header:

```
public List<String> getHeaders() {

    String headerRow = csvFile.substringBefore(nlchar);
    return headerRow.remove(DQUOTE).split(COMMA);
}
```

Code looping through List and getting map value:

```
for (String str : fieldList){
    system.debug(fieldMapping.get(str));
}
```

Comment: Sets and the keys of a map are case sensitive (and also sensitive to leading/trailing whitespace). Can you share with us the values of the column header field in your custom metadata type?

Comment: Also, a bit of a nitpick/rant. Defining constants like `DQUOTE` and `COMMA` are (in my opinion) a complete waste of effort. It takes more characters; changing the value in the future would make the constant names confusing; if `"` or `,` somehow change in the future, having "naked" values of your constants in your code (where  it _could_ be a constant) is going to be the least of your worries.

Comment: @DerekF I did initially think it was a case sensitivity issue, so I tried adding `.toLowerCase()`  when building the Map and retrieving Key values to make sure everything is lower case. First column still returned null when getting from map.